# How to detect if a paragraph has been filled?

Tags: fill-paragraph

**Q:** how can I detect, programmatically, if a paragraph has been filled?

`fill-paragraph` (synonyms fail me) fills a paragraph, and related
`fill-*` functions do analogous things.  Is there a way to detect,
programmatically, if a paragraph has already been filled?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I use a function that fills a paragraph on first invocation, and then alternates between unfilling/filling on subsequent key presses. Maybe that would be useful?

Comment: @Tyler: I am, in fact, trying to toggle between filled and unfilled paragraphs.  I have functions for both, and just need a way to detect which should be deployed.

Comment: That's what I thought. See compact-uncompact-block here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/1057/262

Comment: Here's @phils version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992483/523044

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly hack that works for me:

```lisp
(defun fill-paragraph-p ()
  (let ((hash (buffer-hash))
        result)
    (save-excursion
      (fill-paragraph nil t)
      (setq result (equal hash (buffer-hash)))
      (prog1 result
        (unless result 
          (undo-start)
          (undo-more 1))))))
```

It's simple: hash the current buffer, fill the paragraph, then compare the hash of the buffer and the old hash. If it's the same, the paragraph is filled; otherwise, is not, and we undo `fill-paragraph`.